# python - passing a list of dict in javascript Flask

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary, flask

I know how to pass a variable from Flask (python) to my template html file with `{{data}}`. However I am having trouble accessing each dictionary element and its respective key-value pairs in the list in javascript.

**start.py**

```
def func1():
        data = filter() #returns a list of dictionaries

    return render_template("template1.html", data=data)
```

**template1.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
  .....
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is html: {{data}}</p>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/add.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    myvar = '{{data}}';
    document.write(myvar);

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**add.js**

```
//code to be written here
```

`myvar` and `This is html:` both outputs out the entire list of dictionaries. I've already tried `myvar[0]` but that just outputs `[` for some reason. I have also done:

```
myvar = '{{data|tojson}}';
var parsed = JSON.parse(myvar);
document.write(parsed[0]);
```

but that outputs `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By placing `data` in single quotes you are creating a string. To get python data types into JavaScript, serialize them with `{{ data | tojson }}`.

```
var parsed = JSON.parse('{{data | tojson}}');
```

You may need to escape the output with `safe` filter. See more at [sending data as JSON object from Python to Javascript with Jinja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719592/sending-data-as-json-object-from-python-to-javascript-with-jinja)

Comment: `single quotes` was the important part!

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

```
myvar = '{{data|tojson}}';
var parsed = JSON.parse(myvar);
document.write(parsed[0]);
```

Outputs the `[object Object]` which is the dictionary at the position. So then all you need to do is `document.write(parsed[0].name);` to access its `name` value!

Comment: Don't use `document.write()`; You'll often get warnings from the browser about it. Use `document.querySelector()` or `document.getElementById()` and set it's `.innerText` to your `parsed[0]` value.

Comment: Ah, I see. I figured `document.write()` would be best since I will be using the `dict` values to create new html elements.

Comment: Usually you'd store just data in the json, then loop over it to create elements using `document.createElement()`