# How to send Python data to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, web, jinja2

I am developing the web using google app engine. I used `jinja2` to send data from html to main. pays code. The problem is how to get the data from the javascript of html. Please let me know the correct answer. Thank you.

**main.py**

```py
def get(self):
    db = connect_to_cloudsql()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("set names utf8")
    cursor.execute("""select no, u_name, age, gender, U_adress, phone, car_num, penalty from User;""")

    data = cursor.fetchall() 
    array_list = []

    for row in data:
        temp = (row[0], str(row[1]), row[2], str(row[3]), str(row[4]), row[5], str(row[6]), row[7])
        array_list.append(temp)

    db.close()

    data = json.dumps(array_list)
    template_values = { 'data': data }

    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('User.html')
    self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

and javascript code in html.

```js
var table;

$(function() {
    $.get(function({ data }) {
        var jsonobj = JSON.parse({ data });

        table = $('#userindex').dataTable({ 
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "sDom": "t<'row'<'col-xs-6 col-left'i><'col-xs-6 col-right'p>>",
            "bStateSave": false
        });

        $.each(jsonobj, function(key,value) {
            table.fnAddData(
                value[0],
                value[1],
                value[2],
                value[3],
                value[4],
                value[5],
                value[6],
                value[8]
            );
        });
    });
});
```

this is my error

> datatables.min.js:16 GET https://firststep-2016.appspot.com/function%20(%7Bdata%7D)%7Bvar%20jsonobj%20=%20JSON.parse(%7Bdata%7D);table%20=%20$(' 404 ()

Answer (score 0):

I found PyV8 accidentally today, which I think is what you need. 
It built a js run environment that you can run js code in python to get the text what you want.
Here are the references.

http://www.silverna.org/blog/?p=252

https://code.google.com/p/pyv8/

Answer (score 0):

This's a good answer for sending json data to javascript with jinja. It maybe help you.

[sending data as JSON object from Python to Javascript with Jinja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719592/sending-data-as-json-object-from-python-to-javascript-with-jinja)