# How to dynamically pass FOR LOOP data to a Vue component through Django template?

Tags: vue.js, django-templates, vue-component

I'm still new to Vue and I need to pass for loop data to a Vue component through Django template, but I don't know
exactly how.

In my html page I'm looping a vue component with Django, like this:

```
{% for employee in object_list %}

<app-card name={{ employee.name }} skills-all={{ employee.skils.all }} skill={{ employee.skils.all.name }}></app-card>

{% endfor %}
```

Note: skills-all is a list with lists of skills, and I just wanted to loop through all the skills and show all skills
names in my html list

And my Vue component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div id="card">
        <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="skill in skillsAll">{{ skill }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ["name", "skillsAll", "skill"]
    };
</script>
```

Everything works just fine until I try to make that for loop inside the vue component. Actually I'm very confused about
how am I supposed to loop something inside Vue when the data needs to come from outside the component

Comment: I think you have to pass your skills-all data in a javascript compatible way: fatching it from a REST Api endpoint, or loading them with a javascript file inside your html code. I think you can't share this data from your server side template engine (django/jinja2) and your Vue.js client side template system. Is this what you are trying for?

Comment: @StefanoGiraldi My "name" data is showing normally when I pass it through Django to vue, just like other datas. The issue only happens with more complex data like lists. So I thought if "name" is working fine, "skills-all" should also work, but with the correct way to do it. I just don't know how to pass a list data and loop it inside the Vue component

Comment: You can try to use JSON to pass object data from Django to Javascript code inside the rendered page. Something like this: [sending data as JSON object from Python to Javascript with Jinja](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24719699/1891624)